# multo/magno in comparative adjectives

Tags: comparative

In the sentence "Hi milites sunt magno meliores viribus quam illi." can "multo" substitute for "magno"?

Answer (score 5):

The question should rather be, "can *magno* substitute for *multo*," and the answer is **nullo modo**. It is *multo* that modifies comparatives, *magno* is not used in that way.

- *multo melior* is correct and means "much better"
- *magno melior* is incorrect